# PowerBI skipping month in bar chart

Tags: report, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created the attached dashboard in powerBI. It is a monthly report. That shows the count of item each month. The dates are in this format 1/1/18, 1/2/18, 1/3/18 that the first day of every month
When I created the report powerBI are skiping one month at interval. See Pix attached.
how can i show all months?
[image]

Desired
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you'll need to change the "X-Axis" type to "Categorical". It looks like it's defaulting to Scalar, which makes a continuous axis and picks tick marks based on available space.

Answer (score 1):

You could try decreasing the font size of the month labels since Power BI might be avoiding overlap. You could also try shortening the length of the label from MMM-YYYY to MMM-YY.